# How to insert a row in the table if there is an connection error?

Tags: php, mysql, insert, database-connection

I want to enter a record in the table "logs" if there is an connection error,so how do i do that?

Logs table structure is

```
create table logs(
id int(20) AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
class_name varchar(20),
function_name varchar(20), 
error varchar(200),
error_date datetime));
```

This is my database.php

```
<?php
class Database{
    public $server = "localhost";
    public $user = "root";
    public $password = "";
    public $table_name = "";
    public $database_name = "todo_application";
    public $class_name = "Database";
    public $function_name = "";
    public $database_connection = "";

    //Constructor
    public function __construct(){
        //establishes database connection
        $this->database_connection = new mysqli($this->server,
                                                $this->user,
                                                $this->password,
                                                $this->database_name);
        if($this->database_connection->connect_error)
            die("connection failed".$this->database_connection->connect_error);     
    }

    //Destructor
    public function __destruct(){
        //Terminates the database connection
        $this->database_connection->close();
    }

    //Function to run the database query.
    //Input : Database query.
    //Output : Returns array of the result.
    public function run_query($sql_query){
        $this->function_name = "run_query";
        try{
            if(!$this->database_connection){
                $output = $this->database_connection->query($sql_query);
                if($output){
                    $result["status"] = 1;
                    $result["array"] = $output;
                }
                else{
                    $result["status"] = 0;
                    $result["message"] = "Query error";
                }
            }
            else{
                throw new Exception ("Connection error");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception $error){
            $result["status"] = 0;
            $result["message"] = $error->getMessage();
            $this->error_table($this->class_name, $this->function_name, "Connection error", date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));   
        }
        return $result;
    }
    //Function to insert a error in the table
    //Input : class name, function name , error & date.
    public function error_table($class_name, $function_name, $error_message, $date){
            $sql_query = "insert into `logs`( `class_name`, `function_name`, `error`, `error_date`) VALUES ('$class_name', '$function_name', '$error_message', '$date')";
            $this->database_connection->query($sql_query) ;
    }
 ?>
```

Calling.php

```
<?php
 include "database.php";
 $connection = new Database();
 $sql_query = "select * from some_tablename";
 $output = $connection->run_query($sql_query);
 ?>
```

Can anyone point out where am i wrong, and guide me to find a solution?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can it possible to do an operation if there is a mysql connection error?

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to log the error in the **same** MySQL instance that you couldn't connect to, then the answer is: you probably **can't** do this.

When your application can't connect to the database, it won't be able to save error messages in it.

What you could do is to try to connect again a few times (hoping the connection errors will then go away), but there will be no guarantee that you can ever establish the connection. So it's not safe to rely on that.

Alternatives are to use another database instance for logging problems, logging errors into a text file, sending an email, or simply using PHP's [error_log](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) function to log the error.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use something like

```
<?
$connlog = new mysqli(connection for logs)
$connection = new mysqli(database connection)
if($connection->connect_error) {
    //insert to $connlog
?>
```